# Delete WP option with a click of button

Tags: theme-development, options

I want to delete an option from the wp-options table when clicked on a button in the back-end.

i have created an option with this :

```
get_option( string $option, mixed $default );
```

is there any method in WordPress to get this done? i want to set it back to `$default` so basically deleting the `$option`

Comment: `delete_option()`?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yh.thanks i was looking it , can it be triggered with button click?

Comment: @JacobPeattie yeah duplicate thanks for the guidance

Comment: @JacobPeattie i tried to put the delete_option() within  the answer but it didn't deleted the option

Comment: @JacobPeattie sorry it works ..but if i change form action to  `admin_url('admin-post.php'); ` my custom option page  url it stops working